# Django CKeditor using richTextField but when text is long it wont do paragraph

Tags: django, django-models, ckeditor

Iam using the RichTextUploadingField from CKeditor and when the text is long and need to do the paragraph it wont do it, in spite of using safe in the template

models.py

```
class Manuais(models.Model):
    descrição = RichTextUploadingField(blank=False)
```

template
manual.html

```
{{ manual.descrição | safe }}
```

[image]

Comment: is your website responsive?

Comment: @Steven yes it is, with normal textField models it works fine but with CKeditor richTextFiel it wont work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i was copying a lorem that had one single line, i dindt know that it copys literally what is on the block, but thnx for feedback!